# Bounded /unbounded

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I solved a differential equation and got the solution

$$y=\tan x -\tan x\csc x$$

Which option is correct?

1. $y$ is bounded as $x \to \pi/2$.
2. $y$ is unbounded as $x \to \pi/2$
3. $y$ is bounded as $x \to 0$
4. $y$ is unbounded as $x \to 0$.

Sir which one is/are correct and why?

Comment: Please clean up your lay-out a bit. It's making your question nigh imcomprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the function as $\frac {\sin \,x -1} {\cos\, x}$ and its limit as $x \to \pi/2$ is $0$ by L'Hopital's Rule. Hence it is bounded as $x \to \pi/2$.

Comment: Or use trig. identities to find $$\frac{\cos(\frac\pi2-x)-1}{\sin(\frac\pi2-x)}=-\frac{2\sin^2(\frac{\pi-2x}4)}{2\sin(\frac{\pi-2x}4)\cos(\frac{\pi-2x}4)}=\tan\left(\frac{2x-\pi}4\right)$$ which gives the limits by continuous continuation (cancellation of a factor with a root) without using l'Hopital.

Comment: Or even more simply, extend the fraction by the factor $\sin x+1$ to get via binomial identities $$\frac{\sin^2x-1}{\cos x(\sin x+1)}=-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x +1}$$ which also is non-singular at the points in question.

Answer (score -1):

In the solution, check where the denominator equals $0$. At those points, the solution is unbounded. Everywhere else it is bounded.

Comment: Undefined does not necessarily mean unbounded. For example, $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is bounded at $x\to 0$